# UIView incorrect frame on @3x devices

Tags: swift, layout, uiview, cgrect

I have a really weird bug on **@3x devices** where a `UIView` is visually incorrectly sized.

I insist on the *visually* word because when I print out the frame of that particular view, everything is correct.

**On @2x devices, everything looks fine.**

My view hierarchy is really simple. I have a view (view `B`) inside another one (view `A`).

View `B` is centered in its superview (view `A`).

Really simple right?

Frame of view `B` should be: 
`CGRect(x: 8.5, y: 15.5, width: 19.0, height: 5.0)`

If we scale it with a factor of 3 (to obtain its real dimensions on @3x devices), we should have a rectangle with the following frame:
`CGRect(x: 25.5, y: 46.5, width: 57.0, height: 15.0)`

---

When testing on a @3x device, **visually**, the origin.x of the view is 26px (instead of 25.5), and its width is 56px (instead of 57px).

[image: Frame issue]

Here is the code:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private static let centeredViewSize = CGSize(width: 36, height: 36)

    private let centeredView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    private let rectangleView = UIView(frame: .zero)

    // MARK: - View Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.rectangleView.clipsToBounds = true
        self.rectangleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple

        self.centeredView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.centeredView.addSubview(self.rectangleView)

        self.view.addSubview(self.centeredView)
    }

    // MARK: - Layout

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        self.centeredView.frame.size = ViewController.centeredViewSize
        self.centeredView.center = self.view.center

        let rectangleViewSize = CGSize(width: 19, height: 5)
        let rectangleViewHorizontalOrigin = self.centeredView.bounds.midX - (rectangleViewSize.width / 2)
        let rectangleViewVerticalOrigin = self.centeredView.bounds.midY - (rectangleViewSize.height / 2)
        let rectangleViewOrigin = CGPoint(x: rectangleViewHorizontalOrigin, y: rectangleViewVerticalOrigin)
        self.rectangleView.frame = CGRect(origin: rectangleViewOrigin, size: rectangleViewSize)
    }
}
```

This whole issue seems to come from the horizontal origin.
If I round it like this:

```swift
let rectangleViewHorizontalOrigin = (self.centeredView.bounds.midX - (rectangleViewSize.width / 2)).rounded()
```

The issue is gone. But that's not a solution. I want that view to be perfectly centered in its superview.

**How can I fix this?**

I created a [demo project](https://hostr.co/tefekzurwhN9) so you can try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I run your code. Your frames are perfectly centred at any device. 
Only two things I've changed.

1st in:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

      // Change the order of adding subviews
      self.view.addSubview(self.centeredView)
      self.centeredView.addSubview(self.rectangleView)
}
```

2nd:

I use `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews() 
     }`

instead `override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
     }`

If something will go wrong, please edit your question with new screenshots.
Here is my console output.
[image]

Comment: Hi Alexander, as I said in my question, the console output does show the right frame value. Launch the project on the iPhone 6 Plus (or any other @3x device) in the simulator, take a screenshot with ⌘+S, then mesure the width of the purple rectangle, it will be 56px wide, despite the console showing 57.

Comment: I will discuss it with my team. Maybe somebody has an answer )